# Xamarin IOS debug, app crashes with no error

Tags: ios, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin

When I run app with debug from Visual Studio in IOS Emulator, app launches, shows splash screen and then crashes.
Visual Studio continue showing normal behavior like it is still attached to debug process and everything go according to plan.

When I launch that same app on emulator manually, it works perfectly.

Debug log always as this:

> Loaded assembly:
> /Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/40C63365-3924-44EA-9145-AAF5F59D170F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FED2C1CB-FD8E-441A-856C-66981DB384B5/WebtutorMobileX.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll
> [External] Loaded assembly:
> /Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/40C63365-3924-44EA-9145-AAF5F59D170F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FED2C1CB-FD8E-441A-856C-66981DB384B5/WebtutorMobileX.iOS.app/System.dll
> [External] Loaded assembly:
> /Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/40C63365-3924-44EA-9145-AAF5F59D170F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FED2C1CB-FD8E-441A-856C-66981DB384B5/WebtutorMobileX.iOS.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]

After that app crashes and nothing happens. Visual Studio stays in blessed ignorance.

No errors whatsoever.

This began after I upgraded to 4.7.0.1179 and XCode 11.6. Visual Studio 2019 16.6.5.

Comment: Delete the obj/debug folder and clean/rebuild your project.

Comment: Wish that it were so simple...(

Comment: How about re-install the Xamarin.forms?

Comment: Still nothing...

Comment: Does it work if you downgrade the Xamarin.forms version? If not, it may caused by the visual-studio.

Comment: Maybe I'll try to downgrade it some time later, thing is I will have to also downgrade XCode on Mac side, and everything that involves iOS is really pain in the rear.

Comment: I don't think you need to downgrade XCode if you just want to downgrade  Xamarin.forms version.

Answer (score 2):

Changing iOS Linker settings to "Link Framework SDKs Only" has fixed it for me (if someone still has this problem in 2022).

VS for Mac 17.3.8 - XCode 14 - XF 5.0.0.2515

Answer (score 0):

Put a try/catch block in the `Main.cs` file in the xamarin.ios project and a breakpoint in the catch block, it usually tells you what wrong in this kind of crash.

```
    public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
            // you can specify it here.
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Breakpoint here
        }
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, still nothing. I believe it is something with debugger linking, as that copied debug instance runs smoothly without debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Version 16.7.4 + Xamarin IOS 14.0, debug working again.